# Change email reply's automatic object

Tags: mail.app, email

When I reply to an email, the object is automatically set as "Re: {object of the previous email}".

I would like to **change the "Re:**" and have **"Rép:" instead**.

Is that possible? I didn't find that option in the settings (most likely in "viewing" or "composing"...)

Thanks:)

Comment: If your mac’s language is French, it may do this automatically (happens when I send mail from my phone too)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - from which one might infer that the devs didn't know what re means either, nor did they read RFC 822 ;)

Answer (score 4):

I very much doubt this is editable anywhere - because it doesn't actually mean what people think it means…

Everybody thinks **re** means reply or regarding, but actually it is a word in & of itself.

*Re* is the ablative form of the latin word *res*, meaning 'thing' or 'affair', or 'in the manner of'.
It is not an abbreviation at all.

Refs:
 <sup>Which **is** an abbreviation, of 'references' ;-)</sup>
https://www.dailywritingtips.com/regarding-re/
https://thewritecorner.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/what-does-re-stand-for/
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2520

Another reason to *not* ever change it is that it forms part of the email standard [RFC 822 - Internet Message Format](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), which specifies it as an accepted method to start a title - no email app will ever be looking for anything other than re when it threads successive emails with the same title.

> When used in a reply, the field body MAY start with the
> string "Re: " (from the Latin "res", in the matter of) followed by
> the contents of the "Subject:" field body of the original message.

BTW, I knew where to start researching this information because the first job I had fresh out of school involved legal writing, which frequently uses Re: to indicate subject matter & not to indicate it is a reply.

Comment: [This answer is GREAT!](https://media1.tenor.com/images/4cc9b8a7b008dca4825bafcf15bfbbbd/tenor.gif?itemid=10910755)  +1 (Wish I could give more!) Also see this reference on usage from the 1700's : https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2520

Comment: @Allan - Thank you! I'll add that ELU answer in the refs list.

Comment: Thanks for this very interesting answer! I was actually wondering because I've seen other people's reply with "Rép:"... Maybe it comes from their email client even though as you said it's not standard?